# Use of undeclared identifier 'PFCloud'

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm writing a method that takes a string from a textfield, and sends it over to a cloudcode function on Parse's end. Xcode is giving me the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'PFCloud'`, even though I've imported the parse header in SearchViewController.h. What could be causing this?

SearchViewController.m:

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemSearch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextButton;

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.nextButton) return;
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"averageStars"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSNumber *ratings, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            // ratings is 4.5
                                        }
                                    }];


    }

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}


@end
```

SearchViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Comment: can you post what the log error your are getting when trying to call Parse.com cloud function, is that function exists on Parse.com cloud  code.

Comment: It turns out the problem was that PFCloud.h hadn't imported properly with the Parse framework. I removed Parse framework and reimported it, and it works fine now. Thanks!